# ASUS Wirless-AC1300 PCE-AC56 not recognised

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, broadcom

My new ASUS Wirless-AC1300 PCE-AC56 card is not recognized by lspci.

I have tried following this guide https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2214110.

However, i cannot find any broadcom hardware using lspci -nn -d 14e4:.

A blue light is solid, indicating my wifi card is connected.

Output from lspci:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Root Complex
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) I/O Memory Management Unit
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:01.3 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:03.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe GPP Bridge
00:04.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:07.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) PCIe Dummy Host Bridge
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Internal PCIe GPP Bridge 0 to Bus B
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 59)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 0
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 1
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 2
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 3
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 4
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 5
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 6
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Data Fabric: Device 18h; Function 7
01:00.0 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43d0 (rev 01)
01:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c8 (rev 01)
01:00.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c6 (rev 01)
02:00.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:04.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:06.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:07.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
02:09.0 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 43c7 (rev 01)
04:00.0 USB controller: ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1142 USB 3.1 Host Controller
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
07:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981
08:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 [GeForce GTX 1080 Ti] (rev a1)
08:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GP102 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
09:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 145a
09:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) Platform Security Processor
09:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] USB 3.0 Host controller
0a:00.0 Non-Essential Instrumentation [1300]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1455
0a:00.2 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 51)
0a:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controllernter
```

Comment: WLAN disabled in BIOS?

Comment: I have an ASUS ROG STRIX X470-F Gaming Motherboard and within advanced settings I have enabled the UEFI Network Stack.